# Need help setting up multilevel logistic regression

Tags: r, logistic, multilevel-analysis

I am trying to see the effect of a certain intervention in schools. The outcome variable is binary. We have students within schools. Also students' age is a covariate (doesn't changed before and after treatment).

Would the following model be correct?
\begin{align}
{\rm logit}(p[i]) &\leftarrow \alpha_{\rm school[i]} + \beta_{\rm intervention}\times t[i] + \beta_{\rm age} \times {\rm age}[\rm student[i]],  \\
i &= 1,\ldots,N_{\rm students}  \\
\alpha_j &\sim N(\mu,\sigma_{\rm between\ schools}^2),  \\
j &= 1,\ldots,N_{\rm schools}
\end{align}

Does this look correct?

EDIT: t is 0 (before intervention) or 1(after intervention). There is typically 2 observations per student (1 before, 1 after the intervention), but it is possible that some data is missing, i.e. only 1 observation in some students.

EDIT2: Bonus question about implementation. I am new to lme4. Would it be correct to implement the model as follows in R:

```
require(lme4)
glmer(outcome ~ t + age + (1|school) + (1|student))
```

Comment: how many observations per student do you have (1 or more than 1)? Is the intervention applied at the level of schools or at the level of students?  What is your $t$ variable? (Time coded as before=0, after=1?)

Comment: Two observations per student, 1 before and 1 after the intervention. Although I suspect some of the students may be missing one of the two obeservations (it's a large data set).

Yes, t is 0 (before) or 1 (after)